# Calling one def inside another Python

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am attempting to train a perceptron in Python which has 3 different classes of cats: Tigers, Lions, and Cheetahs. In order to do so, I wish to create a plot of the accuracy progression of the perceptron. Initially, I created 3 python files with the purpose of each file being to train the perceptron for each class. The code below is common to each file - is there a way in python that I could combine the three files and implement the code below as a def?

Common code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import Perceptron as nn

def commonCode(!WHAT PARAMETERS SHOULD GO HERE?!):
```

Ideally, I wish to call the functions Lion and Tiger (see below) here, however I'm not sure what parameters I need to call, nor how to implement this.

```
(weigths, accuracy, accuracy_progression) = nn.perceptronLearning(data,epochs,learning_rate, target_accuracy)

(tp,tn,fp,fn) = p.confusionMatrix(weigths,data)

print('weigths: ', weigths)
print('accuracy: ', accuracy)

print('true positive: %d    true negative: %d',(tp,tn))
print('false positive: %d   false negative: %d',(fp,fn))

title = "%d_iterations_lambda=%f" %(len(accuracy_progression),learning_rate)
path = "./Plots/%s.png" %(title)

plt.title(title)
plt.ylabel('accuracy (%)')
plt.xlabel('iteration')
plt.plot(accuracy_progression)
plt.show()
```

train_Lion.py file:

```
def Lion (cat): 
    if cat == b'Cat-lion':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

filename = 'cat.data'
data = np.loadtxt(filename,delimiter=',',converters={4:lion})
np.random.shuffle(data)

epochs = 30
learning_rate = 0.1
target_accuracy = 100
```

train_Tiger.py file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import Perceptron as nn
def Tiger (cat): 
    if cat == b'Cat-tiger':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

filename = 'cat.data'
data = np.loadtxt(filename,delimiter=',',converters={4:tiger})
np.random.shuffle(data)

epochs = 30
learning_rate = 0.2
target_accuracy = 95
```

etc. The learning rate and the target accuracy vary between the classes, therefore I am not sure whether these have to be passed as parameters? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to be _minimal_? And generally there's nothing against moving your code into a single module (or a function).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question - could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: see [mcve] "…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem"

Comment: I believe I have changed the code in accordance with the Minimal example, apologies for that - I've only just started to learn how to program using python so I'm still not sure how to implement functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might set it up like this:

One class that does the perceptron learning and plotting that you initiate with the epoch, learning_rate, target_accuracy, and data. Then the individual modules can define their specific values and instantiate an instance of the class.

Here's a fairly basic wrapping of your implementation. I return the (weights, accuracy, accuracy_progression) tuple so you can process it further in your individual modules if desired. You can of course, refactor further:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import Perceptron as nn


class PPlotter:
    def __init__(self, epochs, learning_rate, target_accuracy, data):
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.target_accuracy = target_accuracy
        self.data = data

    def plot_accuracy_progression(self):
        (weights, accuracy, accuracy_progression) = nn.perceptronLearning(self.data, self.epochs, self.learning_rate, self.target_accuracy)

        (tp,tn,fp,fn) = p.confusionMatrix(weigths,self.data)

        print('weights: ', weights)
        print('accuracy: ', accuracy)

        print('true positive: %d    true negative: %d',(tp,tn))
        print('false positive: %d   false negative: %d',(fp,fn))

        title = "%d_iterations_lambda=%f" %    (len(accuracy_progression),learning_rate)
        path = "./Plots/%s.png" %(title)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.ylabel('accuracy (%)')
        plt.xlabel('iteration')
        plt.plot(accuracy_progression)
        plt.show()

        return (weights, accuracy, accuracy_progression)
```

Then here's an example of how train_Lion.py might look:

```
import numpy as np
import PPlotter

def Lion (cat):
    if cat == b'Cat-lion':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

filename = 'cat.data'
data = np.loadtxt(filename,delimiter=',',converters={4:lion})
np.random.shuffle(data)

epochs = 30
learning_rate = 0.1
target_accuracy = 100

plotter = PPlotter(epochs, learning_rate, target_accuracy, data)

(weights, accuracy, accuracy_progression) = plotter.plot_accuracy_progression()
```